# How to fix WinRT originate error and holographicspace catastrophic failure exception in Hololens App?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, il2cpp

I've recently started getting the following error periodically in my Hololens App, roughly every minute or so, without changing any of my core app functionalities (mostly UI and bugfixing changes):

```
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\spatialgraphdriverclient.cpp(145)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6FDACA3F: (caller: 6FDAE477) ReturnHr(5) tid(1878) 8007001F A device attached to the system is not functioning.
onecoreuap\analog\input\holographicdriverclientlib\lib\spatialgraphdriverclient.cpp(2114)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6FDAE299: (caller: 6FDAE2F7) ReturnHr(4) tid(1920) 80070006 The handle is invalid.
..
Exception thrown at 0x7703954B (KernelBase.dll) in App.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x8000FFFF : 'You may not call WaitForNextFrameReady again until you present your oldest out-standing frame.'.
analog\input\mirage\publicapi\holographicspace.cpp(1791)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6FCA1CE9: (caller: 6FC9EF41) ReturnHr(13) tid(12c) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure
analog\input\mirage\publicapi\holographicspace.cpp(722)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6FC9EF55: (caller: 6FF7AA25) ReturnHr(14) tid(12c) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure
onecoreuap\windows\analog\input\mirage\stubdll\holographicspace.cpp(541)\Windows.Perception.Stub.dll!6FF7AA39: (caller: 69D25009) ReturnHr(1) tid(12c) 8000FFFF Catastrophic failure
```

This error causes the Hololens 2 to freeze for about 10-15 seconds each time it occurs.
I have not yet found a pattern yet, whether it relates to a certain user event or something happening in my environment.

My question would be, if any of you have seen this before and know a fix or if anyone could maybe point me in the right direction? Or is my device broken? Any help would be very much appreciated!

This is my tech stack:

- Unity3D 2019.2.12f1
- MRTK 2.0.0
- Hololens 2 8362.1234.arm64fre.19h1_release_svc_sydney.191108-1600
- App built with ARM

Best Wishes

Comment: It looks like you have started to develop with the latest HoloLens2 real device. We recommend that you provide more details about your application running on the HoloLens2 device so that we can locate the problem or find a solution, such as the MVCE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Hernando! Thank you for the reply. Before I could create a MVCE the device was reset and now it seems to be working fine again. The problems with the freezes became worse over time and a red line sort of glitch started to appear on the display independant of application. If I run into it again Ill make sure to send you guys a proper bug report since Im positive now it didnt have to do with my app. 
Thanks again for your time!